# yq grab all elements that doesn't contains word powershell

Tags: powershell, yq

I would like to retriev list of all images that **DO NOT** contains `cmp` in `repository` section in format **repository:tag**.
I'm trying to use **`yq`** but I'm facing few problems.

My yaml file structure:

```
actions:
    install: ...
    uninstall: ...
images:
    foo:
        imageType:"docker"
        repository: localhost:3000/cmp/foo
        tag: latest
    bar:
        imageType:"docker"
        repository: localhost:3000/bar
        tag: latest
    fizz:
        imageType:"docker"
        repository: localhost:3000/fizz
        tag: latest
```

My Powershell script:

```
$keys = yq eval 'del(.images | .. | select(.repository == """*cmp*""")) | .images | keys' $porterPath
foreach($key in $keys) {
    $key = $key.Replace("- ", "") #All elements of $keys need to be strip from "- "
    $repository = yq eval ".images | .$key | .repository"
    $tag = yq eval ".images | .$key | .tag"
    $image = $repository":"$tag
    writeToFile($image)
}
```

First yq expression is adding `- repository` to the end of the output list in `$keys` so it looks like this:

```
 - bar
 - fizz
 - repository
```

Why I'm getting `- repository` in the end of `$keys` ?

Is there a better way to transform yaml with yq to get output list contains :
repository:tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yq '.images[] | select(.repository | contains("cmp") | not) | (.repository + ":" + .tag)' file.yaml
```

Explanation:

- traverse into the nodes under 'images' `.images[]`
- filter out all the nodes that contain "cmp" in the repository `select(.repository | contains("cmp") | not)`
- create a string concatenation of " repository:tag"

Disclaimer: I wrote yq